# App ID shows up in JWT token instead of app ID URI?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a 2.0 Azure AD application (registered a BF bot), and I have set up an app ID URI so my users can use it as the aud for auth token.

I could use the the app ID URI to get an JWT token successfully, however the token's aud is not the app ID URI, but the APP ID. Is this the expected behavior?

Tried the same thing with old Azure AD applications and the token had the app ID URI as aud. Actually, if I change the "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" property from 2 to null, the 2.0 Azure AD app would work too.

This is very confusing why did such change made to the new version. Is this by intention so the app should always validate that the aud is the app ID?

Comment: I observed the same thing, seems like it'll always be the client id/app id. Though you can still use either to acquire a token. I think it's better to be clear that it's always one rather than requiring you to know to configure both just in case the caller uses the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I check all type tokens (no old Azure AD app). For now, only the audience of MS graph API and Azure AD graph API is the app ID URI, for others almost is app ID/client id.